# openGL ES image click event in android

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, android-widget

I am using openGL es in android. i have drown a cube with 6 image in its different face.
How can i find the click event on these image. I need to find on which side or on which image the user is clicked and need to perform some actions based on it. please share the code for this...

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to perform a ray/quad intersection with your model faces.

Take a look at [Point-triangle intersection in 3d from mouse coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902348/point-triangle-intersection-in-3d-from-mouse-coordinates) for example

Comment: In android you need to use `GLU.gluUnProject()` as openGL-es does not come with unproject as standard. To get the modelview and projection matrices you need to use `MatrixGrabber` `MatrixTrackingGL` and `MatrixStack` from C:\android-sdk\samples\android-7\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\graphics\spritetext

Then use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setGLWrapper%28android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.GLWrapper%29 `myGlSurfaceView.setWrapper((new GLSurfaceView.GLWrapper() { public GL wrap(GL gl) { return new MatrixTrackingGL(gl); }});`